# Does a dynamically linked executable use the static code of a parent process?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

Let's say I have binary A that dynamically links to some shared library. I statically-compile that library into binary B, then fork/exec binary A from binary B. Will binary A use the static functions in binary B since it is now a child process of binary B?

Answer (score 2):

No, since A is its own binary, it has its own links. Since A was linked dynamically to the library, these links stay to the dynamic library.

Also, a simple exec does not automatically allow A to access the memory of B, so A does not even have the possibility to acces the static library code inside of B, even if it wanted to.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to actually do what I describe and substitute my own functions for ones called from another binary dynamically?

Comment: You could replace the dynamic library with a version of your own code you use in B, then A would call your code instead of the original dynamic library. You could also recompile A to link statically if you have at least the object files. As for "relinking" to a static library I know of no easy solution. Now if you have the source to A and simply want to be able to rewrite function calls to point to different functions, you can use function pointers. Still, this will not work well between two different executables.

Comment: Okay, I can compile my own dynamic library, but would I then be able to fork/exec binary A and set environment variables to override the default Linux loader path so binary A looks, say, in an alternate directory for the shared library instead of /lib? If possible, that would work for my purpose.

Comment: Yes, check out LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much. I'll have a go at this and see if it works!

Comment: Another thought, what if I exec ld.so directly from binary B and pass it arguments to load my own shared library along with executing binary A?

Comment: @Synthetix also check out LD_PRELOAD

Comment: @Synthetix I have never done that, so no idea if that works.